# How to redirect from root to subdomain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a structure folder in my hosting like as:

```
/public_html/
index.php  
aaa.php  
bbb.php  
ccc.php
```

I created a folder name "old", then move all old files into "old". Old is a subdomain like old.mysite.com

```
/public_html/
/old/
index.php   
aaa.php   
bbb.php   
ccc.php
```

But, My site has been Google Index a lot URLs of posts

```
http:/mysite.com/yyyy/dd/example-example-example-abc
http:/mysite.com/yyyy/dd/example-example-example-abc1
http:/mysite.com/yyyy/dd/example-example-example-abc2
.....
http:/mysite.com/yyyy/dd/example-example-example-abc3
```

I want to redirect all URLs to

```
http:/old.mysite.com/yyyy/dd/example-example-example-abc.
http:/old.mysite.com/yyyy/dd/example-example-example-abc1.
http:/old.mysite.com/yyyy/dd/example-example-example-abc2.
.......
http:/old.mysite.com/yyyy/dd/example-example-example-abc3.
```

When i moved all files into "old", Google's not index to that links, and it'll show "404 Page Not Found" when visiter click old link.

How can i do that with .htaccess? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at a permanent URL change, you want a [HTTP 301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

How you do this in your .htaccess file depends on how many URLs you're redirecting, and if anything is likely to conflict if redirecting a whole directory.

To redirect a single URL, add a line similar to the following,

```
redirect /2013/11/example http://old.mysite.com/2013/11/example
```

To redirect a whole directory

```
redirect /2013/11 http://old.mysite.com/2013/11
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you want. One aspect for the google indexing is the response code. Make sure that the response is "301 Moved Permanently". Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html for the apache documentation.

I think this can work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.mysite.com/2013/11/$1 [R=301,L]
```